# Will my hull change neutralise the effects of discharging projectile weapons from a space ship?

Tags: vacuum

There have been many SF stories about how to neutralise the effects of discharging projectile weapons in an enclosed spaceshp environment.
My basic solution to a 9mm or .45 inch hole is to have one or more layers of liquid or gaseous hull cladding which will solidify on contact with oxygen or nitrogen.
A rubbery clot which would seal the hole locally without compromising the rest of the layer would seem like an obvious solution.
Any better ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I get what you're asking, but the "any better ideas"  - we deal with specific constrained questions where it's possible to identify a "best answer", at the moment your question is too open-ended. Your idea about a reactive filler that stops the hole seems a good one, why not ask how to best achieve that with minimum weight/available materials?

Comment: Is this a ship armor problem, a gun problem, a projectile problem, a sealant problem...? Graphene, gyrojets, frangibles, pseudo-silk, or...? A hole is a solution for someone trying to kill everyone, so then it's a space suit problem and a hatch problem.

Comment: Sharing the current objections, I've changed the title, to match the question text and focus things. The opener wants to know, if this hull-change idea will work. I did not change the question body text. @GrumpyShite please undo the action when you don't agree.

Comment: The question should state what the problem actually is for which solutions are sought. A tiny hole a few millimeters wide does not pose any immediate danger and it's pretty easy to fix with a low-tech solution such as a patch of duck tape.

Comment: Reading this over, I think there's an interpretation problem anyway. The word "discharged" suggests we need to solve the issue of *outgoing* projectiles launched from the space ship (the reaction force) but the question text seems to refer to an *incoming* projectiles and a shield of some kind. I changed the title, but that did not solve the issue. @GrumpShite please edit, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: I read the question as about handgun discharges inside the ship. To me that suggests *frequent* firefights inside the ship -- frequent enough to have developed a complicated, expensive self-sealing hull instead of much simpler, cheaper options like *disarming* the knuckleheads. Agree that clarification of the question seems wise.

Answer (score 1):

**Self-healing polymers**

What you describe is a viable way and actually kind of exists, as shown in [Self healing skin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPqFuDKffc8&t=46s&ab_channel=Slate).

There are a number of types of self-healing polymers, for an overview see Figure 1 of [Advances in Self-Healing Polymers, W. Rahman](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/apt/2021/7848088/). For gunshot size holes you probably need capsule or vascular network based.

Both methods work on the same principle, instead of reacting with oxygen, you have a two-component system. So you have two types of liquid spread in mini capsules, or in two distinct vascular networks, throughout your material. Upon rupture, those two liquids mix and solidify, healing the material. The benefit of not relying on oxygen reaction is that the materials can be better and that they have a longer shelf life. It is very hard to keep oxygen out of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest idea would just be to give the space craft much thicker/heavier armor than a person could wear. A simple concrete wall from our world (think parking-garage) will stop a bullet. I'd guess a brick wall could to. That doesn't stop the projectiles from being effective as wearing armor anywhere near the thickness of a typical wall is not an option for people or even heavy vehicles like tanks.

The space craft, aside from being much larger, presumable doesn't need to make a lot of abrupt turns, speed ups, and slow downs. In outer space being heavy would cost very little due to low gravity -- it would mostly just slow down acceleration (again, this effects abrupt turns, speed ups, and slow downs but not much else). Plus, you don't want it to break against any old asteroid that comes by.

Come to think of it, any voyage worthy star ship probably has to withstand much more dangerous projectiles in space than a regular old bullet. This would make the wall-too-strong-and-thick-to-penetrate condition almost automatic.

Comment: MMOD shielding isn't unidirectional. There are usually multiple layers, designed to break a projectile up and slow it down before it hits the actual skin of the craft. It also varies in protection from place to place depending on how likely they are to be hit and how vital they are. I'm not sure I would take it as given that if you shot up the MMOD shield from the inside, it would hold.

Comment: Outside of softer-SF settings with reactionless drives and the like, you almost always want to minimize the weight of your spacecraft. Space is pretty big after all, and the rocket equation imposes some very strict limitations spacecraft design.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Space is big, but all of the cost is in getting up to speed. You can cruise at almost arbitrarily high speeds without significant energy expenditure.

Comment: @Cadence You may well be right, but that doesn't sound like a hard technological barrier.

Comment: @user37344 the cost hasn't gone away just because you can coast. In order to coast anywhere in a sensible time you need to be able to accelerate to your coasting speed, and the rocket equation will still bite you.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yeah, I get that. I guess the OP would have to decide things like typical travel time and how futuristic the propulsion system is to do a cost-benefit on the weight issue. I do have a hard time believing armor much thicker than human/vehicle-worn armor is not an option, however. And that is the key premise of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

/how to neutralise the effects of discharging projectile weapons in an enclosed spaceshp environment./

**Do not allow weapons capable of puncturing the hull on board.**

This is the no duh approach to minimizing gun harm.  No guns.  If you are dead set your shipmates are going to shoot each other from time to time you can arm them with weapons that cannot penetrate the ships hull.  Rubber bullets.  [Rubber ducks](https://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Duckling_20Ammo_20Shotgun#1336487456).  Beanbags.  Painball guns with paralytics and pain potion.  Taser nets.  Goo.  Grabber drones.  Quarterstaves.  You can give one of each type to each crew person so everyone will feel special.  Anything but something that is going to punch a hole in the hull.

If your spacecraft is being boarded by persons armed with guns, you have already surrendered with the understanding that you will not be summarily killed by the people taking over your ship.  Because if that were going to be the case you would just destroy the ship; you and them too.